# Congratulations, Arturo!

Tags: discussion, specific-user, celebration

I think congratulations are due to Arturo Magidin on hitting 100k reputation points here on MSE! All the users of this site are better off for his tireless contributions, and we appreciate his positive influence on mathematics and mathematics education via this site.

Comment: What next?  [Arturo Magidin Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)? :)  Well there's always [200k to look forward to](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/).

Comment: Pwnd. (Congrats Prof!)

Comment: With 2k answers and 100k we have an average of 50 points per answer (and this is without considering community wiki and reputation caps) which leads me to believe that every person which caps is actually paying the excess reputation to Arturo! :-)

Comment: Hear! Hear! Congrats Arturo!

Comment: Congratulations, Arturo!

Comment: [By my estimate](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/60382/61594/), Arturo reached 100K a long time ago if we count unrealized rep. It looks like as of the last data dump, it would have been around **125K+**, if I've done the query and calculation correctly. Congrats.

Comment: @cardinal: I just ran a rep recalc on Arturo's account, but it only increased by 10 points to 100,591. Which is still an absolutely amazing number - congratulations, Arturo!

Comment: For 10k+ users, since it was deleted: [How do I be like Arturo Magidin?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76564/how-do-i-be-like-arturo-magidin)

Comment: @Zev The irony...

Comment: @Zev: I don't think a rep recalc will catch it. This is unrealized rep, mostly from hitting the 200-rep-per-day limit, I believe and some from votes on CW posts.  About 6K or so of it is the latter. Sorry I did not make that very clear the first time around. :)

Comment: @cardinal: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant by unrealized. 25k+ sounds much more believable as an amount lost to rep caps and CW than as a temporary discrepency :)

Comment: Congrats @ArturoMagidin!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Indeed I am so late here to congratulate you here. Whenever I ask a question, you help me directly or in other ways. Your comments here in this site have assisted many step by step. I have found a few like you in my academic life. It seems you are devoting yourself here. I inly Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Thank you kindly, one and all. Now, if I can only get as much done in my research...

Comment: Okay, I say we all pool together and help Arturo out by asking a series of ever-so-slight generalizations of results mentioned [here](http://www.ucs.louisiana.edu/~avm1260/research/results.html).

Comment: Arturo, have you ever considered writing books or expository articles?  Putting your gifts for explaining on a wider stage even than math.SE could be a real service to mathematics.

Comment: I've eventually gotten the impression that Arturo is accidentally saving sections of his still-unpublished expository textbook as math.SE answers instead of as files on his computer... ;)

Comment: @J.M. If your impression is true, that book must cover a wiiiide range of topics!

Comment: congrats, and you've got email!

Comment: @MikeSpivey: I've written one expository article that I enjoyed immensely; and at some point I and my coauthor thought of trying to turn some of his course notes on algebraic curves into a book. But neither he nor I have been blessed with an overabudance of time, I would need to learn a lot of stuff (part of the reason I offered was to force myself to learn about it), and the project has not gone anywhere...

Comment: Here's how to get research done: Post the questions from your research here and use your massive rep to add bounties. You'll get answers in no time and have the best thesis ever.

Comment: @Jeff...uh, see the link in Cam's comment (first one below this answer). :)

Comment: Prison did wonders for André Weil's research.

Comment: @Jeff: It's more than a bit late for my thesis to get any better...

Comment: @Arturo, thank *you*!

Answer (score 42):

Indeed, kudos! You're actually the first user on the *entire network* to reach this 100k threshold outside of Stack Overflow -- which [is 333x larger by my current (poor) math calculations](http://stackexchange.com/sites). Yes, even before the older and larger sites like Super User and Server Fault, etc.

I also announced this on Twitter to ~62k followers. Congrats!

https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/164058222368530432

Comment: I got mentioned in twitter? I fear this means the imminent demise of the latter... or at least, its descent into irrelevancy. (-:

Comment: This really says something about math. People interested in math, especially knowledgeable people, seem to have broad interest and knowledge. Perhaps this is true in Stack Overflow but the knowledgeable people there and elsewhere are not really interested in answering simple beginner questions. OTOH, even simple beginner questions can embody interesting math. But of course @Arturo *is* a special person.